# JQuery reusable dialog with different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm new to JQuery and I can't create reusable dialog box. Here is my code

```
    $(function () {
    $("#baseDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 520,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });
    $("#baseDialogOpener").click(function () {
        $("#baseDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
```

I use this dialog box like this:

```
<input id="baseDialogOpener" type="button" value="Update" />
    <div id="baseDialog" title="Test Dialog" class="divClass">
    <!-- here goes some ASP .NET MVC 2 code -->
    </div>
```

The problem is that I want to reuse this dialog many times in many pages but with different html content and I have no idea how to do this, because I can't use class attribute because of styles that I need to use too. I cant use id attrubutes with the same values at the same page. 
And there is no way I can use it like this? Maybe with another attribute than id (class is reserved for css)?
  `<input id="baseDialogOpener" type="button" value="Update" />

      <div id="baseDialog" title="Test Dialog" class="divClass">

    <form>...</form>

    </div>

<input id="baseDialogOpener" type="button" value="Update 2" />

    <div id="baseDialog" title="Test Dialog 2" class="divClass">

    <form>...</form>

    </div>`
Looking forward to your answes.
**UPDATE**: I have the code above executed by using class attribute, but all dialogs appear at once when I click button. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog box can load content from an .htm file from the server when it's opened.

You can use something like this :

```
$("#baseDialogOpener").click(function () {
    $("#baseDialog").load('content.htm');
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE:**  This code shows how to have the same .click() display different contents based on the button.

```
$("dialogButton.").click(function () {
    $("#baseDialog").load($(this).data('content'));
    return false;
});


<input type="button" value="first" id="button1" class="dialogButton" data-content="content1.htm" />
<input type="button" value="second" id="button2" class="dialogButton" data-content="content2.htm" />
```

Comment: And there is no way I can use it like this?  `<input id="baseDialogOpener" type="button" value="Update" />
    <div id="baseDialog" title="Test Dialog" class="divClass">
    <form>...</form>
    </div><input id="baseDialogOpener" type="button" value="Update 2" />
    <div id="baseDialog" title="Test Dialog 2" class="divClass">
    <form>...</form>
    </div>`

Comment: if there were multiple dialog boxes, they would all open `content.htm` when `#baseDialogOpener` was clicked.

Comment: So the only way I can avoid this is giving them different names?

Comment: I would assume that different buttons would open different content, therefore the .load() would contain whichever file was required for each separate button.

Comment: @kernel_mode:  valid html says that only one element can have an id, so your above comment would be invalid.  jquery only returns the first element i such a case.  i'll update my answer with a way to have different buttons open different files if that's what you're needing...

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `class` in place of your `id`.

For instance, instead of:

`<div id="baseDialog" title="Test Dialog" class="divClass">`

Use

`<div title="Test Dialog" class="divClass baseDialog">`

Then you can reference it in your javascript:

Where you have

```
$("#baseDialogOpener").click(function () {
        $("#baseDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
```

Try

```
$(".baseDialogOpener").click(function () {
        $(this).children(".baseDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
```

`$(this)` just grabs whatever was clicked, so you can have multiple classes of the same kind.

Comment: Yes, I know, but class is reserved for css.

Comment: javascript (jQuery) uses class and id - it's not "reserved" just for css at all. Unless you are saying that `#baseDialogOpener` is an already used class, to which I would strongly suggest using different naming conventions.

Comment: By "reserved" I mean that I ness this attribute to apply styles.

Comment: right - you'd have to change it in your css as well. In your .css file, rename `#baseDialogOpener` to `.baseDialogOpener` and it would do the same thing.

Comment: Oh, I just forgot that I can do like this: class="class1 class2 class3".